# in Blueprint.js when I try to use popover into an overlay. Second one close by popover closing

Tags: overlay, popover, apiblueprint, blueprint-css, blueprint

When I try to use popover inside Overlay, it closes when popover close. It looks like popover's closing remove something from body element.

Comment: Please add some codes you've done so far.

Comment: please always to insert code in your questions